# To batch reduce a space in the file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, file-rename

After batch rename so many files using a batch file, I found that the naming structure looks like below:

FILENAME__###.jpg

There are two spaces (the two underscores above) between the FILENAME and the numbering ###. How can I remove one space (or reduce that 2 spaces to 1 space) for all of the files (may with different suffixes) under a directory with the above naming structure using a batch command file in the command prompt of Windows system.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if I were you I'd fix the initial rename instead of post-process the wrongly named files...

Comment: Those many files are renamed already before I found the problems.

Comment: I see... What have you tried so far? please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't any file names that begin with space, then

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("*  *") do for /f "tokens=1* eol= delims= " %%A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%A %%B"
```

The above will handle a single run of any number of consecutive spaces and convert that run into a single space.

If you have multiple runs of spaces, then you can simply parse out more tokens. You don't have to worry about parsing more tokens than exist because Windows automatically trims trailing spaces and dots from file names. It is possible to handle up to 31 space runs (32 tokens) with a single `FOR /F`, and it is simple to handle 25 space runs (tokens A through Z). The code below handles 9 space runs, which is likely more than enough.

```
@echo off
for %%f in ("*  *") do for /f "tokens=1-9* eol= delims= " %%A in ("%%f") do ^
ren "%%f" "%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G %%H %%I %%J"
```

Or if you get a hold of [JREN.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081), a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression renaming utility, then you can use:

```
jren "  +" " " /fm "*  *"
```

The JREN.BAT solution will handle all instances of consecutive spaces, no matter how many.

If you use JREN.BAT within another batch script, then you must use `call jren` so that control returns to your script.

Comment: Thanks dbenham for your solution. I tried the script with a dummy file with a name of 

AAAA  BBBB  CCCC  DDDD.jpg

The first run changes it to

AAAA BBBB  CCCC  DDDD.jpg

But then it doesn't work for the consecutive runs for the other multi-spaces. Please advise, many thanks.

Comment: @garrison - Ugh! That's what I get for not testing. Of course it fails - the FOR /F always breaks token A at the first encountered space, so no additional changes are made. Thanks for letting me know. I've edited my answer with a pure batch solution that truly works with multiple instances of space runs.

Comment: It works fine now, million thanks for your great help!